# python embedded image thunderbird

Tags: python, image, thunderbird

I cannot get thunderbird to show any embedded images I send in emails via python. It shows small empty boxes in the image and the image underneath the body (not a typical attachment).

the emails are correct in Outlook and Yahoo.

I must be missing a header?

```
self.msg = MIMEMultipart( )
fp       = open( path2img , 'rb')
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<imagename>')
msgImage.add_header('Content-Disposition' , 'inline' , filename='image.png')
msgImage.add_header('Content-Type' , 'image/png')
self.msg.attach(msgImage)
```

my image source in the email body is:

```
<img src="cid:imagename">
```

I have looked everywhere and cannot work out why!! please help.

(my Python might not be great, but good enough for Outlook  / Yahoo)

thanks in advance

Comment: Thunderbird must be blocking all images may be.. . like security issues.. . check out for show images/its safe kind of options.. .

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the 'filename' value, not the Content-ID. For instance:

```
<img src="cid:image.png"/>
```

See this question for more info: [Display an attached image on the HTML message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304618/display-an-attached-image-on-the-html-message/8304696#8304696)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just change the MIMEMultipart constructor to:

```
self.msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
```

and it will work.